# conflict with scroll event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a header that appears on scroll and is fixed, but on the products page I also want navigation to be fixed when it scrolls to a certain point. The issue I am having, is that they are both the same event. So I include the nav code with the header code in the same event, but this means that when I am on pages other than the products page, the action no longer works, as it cannot find the elements on the product page. If I do them separately, it conflicts with the same event.

I can do it with on page script using server side code, but I was wondering if there was a way to get around it, if it was still in the JS file.

```
height2 = $('#product_nav_cont').offset().top;
header2 = $('#scroll_header_cont').outerHeight();
empty_div = "<div class='empty_div' style='width:100%; height:"+header2+"px; display:block;' ></div>";
$(window).scroll(function() {
    height = $('#main_header_nav_cont').outerHeight();
    scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > height) {
        $('#scroll_header_cont').fadeIn(400);
    } else {
        $('#scroll_header_cont').stop().hide();
    }

    scroll2 = $(this).scrollTop();
    pos2 = height2-header2
    //$('#scroll_logo').text(height)
    if(scroll2 > pos2) {
        $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'fixed','top':header2,'width':'100%'});
        if( !$('.empty_div').length) {
            $('#main_header_nav_cont').after(empty_div);
        }
    } else {
        $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'static','top':'0'});
        $(".empty_div").remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: Height2 and header2 don't look like variables that have been defined.

Comment: sorry, added them in now

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if the element is present on the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if (document.getElementById('main_header_nav_cont')) //check if this element is on the page. If not it returns null and it won't execute this if clause.
    {
        height = $('#main_header_nav_cont').outerHeight();
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll > height) {
            $('#scroll_header_cont').fadeIn(400);
        } else {
            $('#scroll_header_cont').stop().hide();
        }
    }
    scroll2 = $(this).scrollTop();

    //$('#scroll_logo').text(height)
    if (document.getElementById('product_nav_cont')) //same thing here
    {
        pos2 = height2-header2;
        height2 = $('#product_nav_cont').offset().top;
        if(scroll2 > pos2) {
            $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'fixed','top':header2,'width':'100%'});
            if( !$('.empty_div').length) {
                $('#main_header_nav_cont').after(empty_div);
            }
        } else {
            $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'static','top':'0'});
            $(".empty_div").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, I knew it would be something simple like that, just couldnt think of it.

Comment: The header is fixed on the products page, but not the nav, and nothing works on other pages.

Comment: if it was a # then it still hasnt made any difference

Comment: oh, i copied the code and it worked on the products page, but still not the other pages

Comment: Try again. And remove height2 = $('#product_nav_cont').offset().top; from the top of the code.

Comment: then the other pages work, and the header works, but the nav doesnt.

Comment: What if I used if($('#product_nav_cont').length)